# Limit number of users a role can create

Tags: theme-development, users, user-roles, user-registration

Just wondering if there is a way to limit the amount of users a specific role can create?

For example, if Editors can create new accounts, I only want them to be able to create 20, and then they can't create any more...

I've Googled and all I seem to get is limit the amount of posts a role can create. Not what I want...

Thanks